# Conditional Expectation of Sum

Tags: probability, statistics

I am asked to prove the linearity (essentially) of the expected value.

$ E(X_1 + X_2 | Y=y) = E(X_1|Y=y) + E(X_2| Y=y)$

My ideal of the proof seems like it is missing something, yet I cannot identify what else I might need. I only have been given that $X_1, X_2, Y$ are random variables and no information about if they are i.i.d and so forth. Here is my current draft of proof:

$E(X_1 + X_2 | Y=y )$

$ = E(\sum_{1}^2 X_i | Y=y)$

$=\sum_{x} \sum_{1}^{2} X_i (f_{X|Y} (X|Y)) $

$=\sum_{x} (X_1 + X_2)f_{X|Y} (X|Y) $

$=\sum_x X_1f_{X|Y} (X|Y) + X_2f_{X|Y} (X|Y)$

$=\sum_x X_1f_{X|Y} (X|Y) + \sum_xX_2f_{X|Y} (X|Y)$

$= E(X_1|Y=y) + E(X_2| Y=y)$

Comment: I don't understand the notation in your third line $\sum_x \sum_1^2 X_i(f_{X|Y}(X|Y)$.  What does $\sum_x$ mean?  Why are there no small $x$ dummy variables in that sum? What does $f_{X|Y}(X|Y)$ mean? How did that expression become a random variable rather than an expectation of a random variable?

Comment: My guess is that you are expected to modify a formula like $$E[X_1+X_2] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (x_1+x_2)f_{X_1, X_2}(x_1,x_2)dx_1 dx_2$$ to using $f_{X_1,X_2|Y=y}(x_1, x_2)$.